# Ignore xml tags while serializing pojo fields to xml

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using jackson library to map POJO to XML.

```
compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.0')
```

While serializing I need to ignore some of the fields. This is my POJO class. For example, the field `lineNumber` should be ignored.

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class InvoiceLineItem {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "LineNumber")
    @XmlTransient
    private Integer lineNumber;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ProductCode")
    @XmlTransient
    private String productCode;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ProductDescription")
    @XmlTransient
    private String productDescription;
}
```

I am using `@XmlTransient` with `XmlAccessorType` to ignore the fields. But the `lineNumber` field annotated with XmlTransient is not ignored while serializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)`
annotation to the `lineNumber` field.

Even thought it looks like a JSON thing,
the Jackson `XmlMapper` identifies the annotation and reacts accordingly.

Edit
The conclusion XmlMapper should support JSON serizlization is an example of the following, incorrect attempt at reasoning:

1. All men are mortal.
2. Socrates was mortal.
3. Therefore, all men are Socrates.

The XmlMapper is not a wrapper class around ObjectMapper.
It came after ObjectMapper and appears to share many features,
like the handling of some JSON annotation.

Comment: Thank you,  it works as expected. But how come xmlMapper could interpret @JsonProperty. If this is the case does all annotation related to json works with xmlMapper?

Comment: In the history of the Jackson project, the ObjectMapper (for JSON) came first.  The XmlMapper appears to have been built on top of the ObjectMapper.

Comment: As XmlMapper is built on top of ObjectMapper then JsonSerialize should work with XmlMapper like how it works with ObjectMapper.But in my case, @JsonSerialize with custom serializer on top of any class fields is not working. Kindly help me out to figure this out.